# Conditional IF Statements in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I've written this function to respond to an event listener in a separate function:

EDIT: Updated with working code.

```
       function greyOutItems(event:Event):void {

        if (DisableCheckBox.selected) {
            myComboBox.alpha = 0.5;

            myComboBox.enabled = false;
            trace("hide combobox success");
        }
        if (DisableCheckBox.selected == false) {
            myComboBox.visible = true;
            myComboBox.enabled = true;
            trace("visible");
        }
    }
```

The first `if` statement works well, hiding the ComboBox when the user clicks on the CheckBox, but I want the user to be able to uncheck the same CheckBox and make the ComboBox visible again.

Ideally, rather than setting the alpha property to 0, I'd prefer if the ComboBox was "greyed out" although I haven't yet found the property to do so.

Comment: Thank you this fixed it, fairly simple i know. Post your comment as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Is `myComboBox` a movieclip?

Comment: @Sim It is a movieclip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditionals will **always** be true because you are setting them to that value in the conditional. "=" is for "assigning" properties *only*. "==" is "equivalent to". So `if (DisableCheckBox.selected = true)` actually sets the `selected` property to true and the way a conditional works, because it successfully set the value, it is marked as a true statement.

```
function greyOutItems(event:Event):void {
    if (DisableCheckBox.selected == true) {
        myComboBox.alpha = 0;
        trace("success");
    }
    if (DisableCheckBox.selected == false) {
        myComboBox.alpha = 1;
        trace("revisible");
    }
}
```

In this case, you also should have used `else` instead of your second conditional, however. An else statement will run slightly faster at runtime (since it doesn't have to check for the second condition, it just runs the else if all conditions are false). Not enough to be noticeable, but it adds up if you are doing this many times

Comment: It's also worth noting that unless `DisableCheckBox` is a Singleton or `selected` is a static property, it should not be capitalized. All object names should be lowercase, camelcase. All class names should be uppercase, camelcase.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statements are wrong. `=` is assignment. You should use `==` or just use the `selected` directly in the if statement.

```
if (DisableCheckBox.selected) {
    myComboBox.alpha = 0;
    trace("success");
}
if (!DisableCheckBox.selected) {
    myComboBox.alpha = 1;
    trace("revisible");
}
```

Comment: thank you, can you tell me how to give my comboboxes the appearance of being "greyed out" though as well?

Comment: You can try setting alpha to `0.5` and setting `mouseEnabled` to `false`

Answer (score 1):

If `myComboBox` is a movieclip, one way you could "grey out" the buttons rather than using the `alpha` property is to add a second frame to it where it's behind a grey, half alpha box or similar effects you can control much better in the Flash editor.

In your code you'd then use `myComboBox.gotoAndStop(2)` to grey the box out or `myComboBox.gotoAndStop(1)` to return it to normal.